# Splunk spath vs plain search performance

Tags: json, logging, splunk

Assuming that I have json logs formatted like

```
{
    level: INFO,
    logger: com.mantkowicz.test.TestLogger,
    message: Just a simple test log message
}
```

what is the difference between such two searches:

```
A) ... | message = "Just a simple test log message"
B) ... | spath message | search message = "Just a simple test log message"
```

Is there any performance drawback? Should I prefer one of these?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably go with the first approach and remove the need for `spath`.

Depending on your use case, you could also look at JSON indexed extractions, `KV_MODE=json` which can do the field extractions at index time, rather than every search.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that search `A` doesn't work if there is no 'message' field extracted.  In that case, you'll need search `B` or extract fields at index-time as @Simon Duff suggested.